# Shortcut to testing PHP code

Tags: php, python, interpreter, shortcut

Having a python interpreter is really useful as it lets you quickly type in few commands and verify output; making it easier to understand syntax.

However, in PHP, every time I want to try something out I have to - create a PHP script, save it, run it in my browser.

Is there a shortcut that I am missing out on for PHP that would make things simpler?

Comment: There is also a PHP CLI http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.php

Comment: php scripts usually intended to be run in browsers. nothing bad in it. but if you want to use php for the system scripting, it has a console as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can run php CLI in interactive mode ;)

```
php -a
```

in interactive mode you need to type the script with start and end tags

```
<?php echo 'Hello!'; ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [PHP Designer](http://www.mpsoftware.dk/phpdesigner.php). It will make your job much easier.

Comment: I love PHPDesigner, the only drawback is, that there is no autocompletition for the SPL like in Zend-Studio.

Answer (score 1):

Or you could use [phpUnit](http://www.phpunit.de/) , unit testing for php

Comment: While I am all for UnitTesting I don't think this is what the OP is after here.

Comment: OP? (Just trying to get a hang of the lingo here at SO :-)